# Why is a period in a character class not matching only a literal period

Tags: javascript, regex

```
console.log("<p>email@address.com</p>".match(/([a-zA-Z0-9.-_+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,10})/g))
```

> `["<p>email@address.com"]`

Can someone help me understand why the `< >` characters are matching this regular expression? I always thought that a `.` in a character class `[]` was interpreted literally.

When I remove the `.`, it no longer returns that paragraph tag.

Comment: `.-_` looks suspicious. There's a world between `.` and `_`.

Comment: This matches a range `.-_` from ascii 46 - 95 where the `<` and `>` are 60 and 62

Comment: _Note to self_: Always put `-` at the end of a character class.

Comment: Side note on the whole "regex for email addresses" - [this is an interesting read](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) on the subject.

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a potential hidden problem in your regex:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9.-_+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,10}
```

If you look closely at the first character class, you will see that hyphen defines a range between `.` and `_`.  This could be unintentionally including characters which you don't want.  Try moving the hyphen to the end of the character class:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,10}
```

Here is a regex demo for `[a-zA-Z0-9.-_+]` [before](https://regex101.com/r/M6G6zh/1) and [after](https://regex101.com/r/M6G6zh/2).  Note that `@` and `^` were being matched in the original version, but then stopped being matched after moving `-` to the end of the class.

Comment: 'Doh! yes that did it.

Answer (score 2):

You are matching `.-_` (all characters in the range from `.` to `_`) which includes all the characters in the ASCII range 46-95.

To fix this, escape the `-` by writing `\-`

```
([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_+]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,10})
            ^ note backslash here
```

Comment: You could also just change the order. `._-`

Comment: Well if we're discussing tricks, you can put a `]` as the first character of the set items too.  Leading to the curious regular expression  `[]-]`  which matches a `]` or a `-`